# Add CSS Class to header.Cells

Tags: c#, css

I need to add CssClass to a table that is being generated automatically through C#. Here is the code that creates the table:

```
TableHeaderRow header = new TableHeaderRow();
cell1 = new TableCell { Text = "Brand" };
cell2 = new TableCell { Text = "Product Name" };
cell3 = new TableCell { Text = "Size/Weight" };
cell4 = new TableCell { Text = "Quantity" };
cell5 = new TableCell { Text = "" };
header.Cells.Add(cell1);
header.Cells.Add(cell2);
header.Cells.Add(cell3);
header.Cells.Add(cell4);
header.Cells.Add(cell5);
```

I have attempted two ways of adding CssClass to two of the cells:

```
header.Cells(cell3).CssClass = "mobile2";
header.Cells(cell4).CssClass = "mobile1";
```

Using this method creates build error CS1955, Non-Invocable member "TableRow.Cells" cannot be used like a method.

So I changed the () to [] and then got build error CS1503, Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' to 'int'.

What is wrong with the method I am using to assign a CssClass to cell3 and cell4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple `cell3.CssClass = "mobile2";` will work.

You already *have* the cell that you want to give a class, no need to look it up in the header.

Or you could have used `header.Cells[2].CssClass = "mobile2";`. The Cells collection needs the index (zero based) at which the required cell is found.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks. I knew it would be something simple I was overlooking.